# phpmailer smtp on outlook server : 554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm not getting this error `554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message.`  or I didn't find the solution. Can anyone please help me with this error? Here is my source file Link [Mail.php](https://bridgewaydigital.com/mails.php)

Answer (score 1):

As always, the first thing to do is *read the error message*. Here it says "send as denied", so I would guess that this means your from address is different to your account address (i.e. `$mail->Username` is different to `$mail->From`), and that your mail server does not allow sending from arbitrary addresses.

Your version of PHPMailer is also outdated, which never helps.

Comment: My domain is using outlook server and I also send the message is using outlook emails to send and receive emails. so where I doing wrong in it.

Comment: you can reload this link on your browser.

Comment: It's not possible to tell because you have not posted your code in your question.